# Begining with Relationships with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, database

I'm starting with MySQL database relashionships and I have a question.
I'm going to put in an exemple:

```
Table A = customer  
Table B = products  
Table C = sales
```

I wanna know how can I make a relationship with these tables where "sales" has only one customer and multiple produts.
The "sales" table can't have a Primary Key with both foreign keys, cuz it will have multiple products.
I could create a ´idsale´, but how I would structure the table to receive multiple products?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Costumers and Sales have a `ONE-TO-MANY` relation. You could add a `customer` reference on the Sales table

```
Table sales
- id PK
- customers_id FK
```

Sales and Product have a `MANY-TO-MANY` relation. You will need a new table to map this relation

```
Table sales_has_products
- sales_id FK
- products_id FK
```

Comment: That kinda clarifies. So, if I need the list of that sale's product, I will execute `SELECT * FROM sales_has_products WHERE sales_id = 'SALEID';` something like that, right?

Comment: with that query you will get the `product_id`, for get all the columns for the product you will have to do a `join`: `SELECT p.* FROM sales_has_products sp INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = sp.products_id WHERE sp.sales_id = 'SALEID'`

Comment: @Dédi You may also want to include a quantity column in this table

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a fourth table, let's call it `productSale`, that has its own primary key, as well as foreign keys the sale ID and the product ID. `Sale`, then, will just have an ID and the foreign key of the customer ID (as well as any additional info you want, of course.)
This way, a sale can include multiple items of the same product (because all `productSale` rows have a unique ID), and all of the items included in a sale can be found by querying `productSale` by the specific sale ID.

Comment: It doesn't need its own surrogate PK. The other columns are enough.

Comment: That will depend on how you want to handle selling multiple instances of one product in a single transaction.

Comment: True but it would be odd to choose that method